# EntityFramework Code first migrations not running after deploying to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing a web application in ASP.NET using code first migrations. It works fine locally but after deploying to Azure, code first migrations are not executed. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) step by step a few times but I have not been able to spot what is wrong on my setup. Here is the relevant code:

**DB Context:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {}

    public DbSet<BC_Instance> BiocloudInstances { get; set; }

    static ApplicationDbContext() {}

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        var conv = new AttributeToTableAnnotationConvention<SoftDeleteAttribute, string>(
           "SoftDeleteColumnName",
           (type, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnName);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(conv);
    }
}
```

**Connection strings:**

*(it is replaced on publish, but just in case)*

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bcplatform2;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

**Code First Migrations configuration**

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<bcplatform2.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(bcplatform2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context));
        const string name = {name here};
        const string password = {pass here};
        const string adminRole = {role};
        string[] roles = new string[] { adminRole, ApplicationRole.DefaultRoleName };

        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
            {
                roleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(role));
            }
        }

        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == name))
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name, credit = 10 };

            userManager.Create(user, password);
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, adminRole);
            userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Publication wizard**
[image]

**Entity framework section in deployed Web.config**

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
  <contexts>
    <context type="bcplatform2.Models.ApplicationDbContext, bcplatform2">
      <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[bcplatform2.Models.ApplicationDbContext, bcplatform2], [bcplatform2.Migrations.Configuration, bcplatform2]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken={token}">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish" />
        </parameters>
      </databaseInitializer>
    </context>
  </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

**Connection strings in deployed Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:{serverid}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={dbid};User Id={user};Password={password}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:{serverid}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={dbid};User ID={user};Password={password}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you inspect the deployed web.config file?

Comment: No, but connection with the database is not the problem. The problem is the migration is not applied nor is the db seeded. I'll look it up though

Comment: @ErikEJ I modified the Question to include this information. Indeed I'm not sure it's correct where it says `<parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />` or `<databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion\`2`
Do you know if that is the way it should be?

Comment: Is it necessary to put PublicKeyToken={token} into databaseInitializer?
Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

Comment: @VadimSentyaev I don't really know. This is automatically generated code by the deployment process. The hope would be that it does the right thing. The source you mention doesn't really specify if `PublicKeyToken` should or shouldn't be there either right? Ps. Just to clarify, I replaced the actual value with `{token}` not to share it online

Comment: Try to remove "parameters" section from "databaseInitializer". Or check if connection string "DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish" exists in Azure web-site configuration.

Comment: By web-site configuration you mean the web.config file? If so, it exists, together with a `DefaultConnection` which is exactly the same. As for removing the `parameters` section I don't know how to do it because it's code generated on the deployment process: it's not in the project in VisualStudio. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case. Tutorial you provide does not have default constructor in ApplicationContext, and your code has it. So, probably that's the reason of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(bcplatform2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context));
    const string name = {name here};
    const string password = {pass here};
    const string adminRole = {role};
    string[] roles = new string[] { adminRole, ApplicationRole.DefaultRoleName };

    foreach (string role in roles)
    {
        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
        {
            roleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(role));
        }
    }

    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == name))
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name, credit = 10 };

        userManager.Create(user, password);
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, adminRole);
        userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
    }
}
```

It did not complete but didn't show any error on the publication output making the error difficult to spot. I removed the seed method and the migrations worked.

Some advice to avoid similar problems in the future would be not use the "Use this connection string at runtime" and "Execute code first migrations" options from the publication wizard. If something goes wrong the output won't always show an error and it gives little control over how Web.config is modified.

Instead, replace the connection string in Web.config before publishing or configure the Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config accordingly.

Comment: yes but I don't know what is wrong with it since the same code completes successfully at a 'later stage' but it fails on the seed operation

Answer (score 7):

You can update your Web.config file in Solution

It's not necessary provide connection string inside "context" section, because you already provide it in ApplicationDbContext constructor.

Also, with this config, you can uncheck "Execute code first migration" in Publication Wizard.

Your EF section should look similar to this (**most important is "context" section**):

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
<contexts>
  <context type="TestWebApp.Models.AppContext, TestWebApp">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[TestWebApp.Models.AppContext, TestWebApp], [TestWebApp.Migrations.Configuration, TestWebApp]], EntityFramework" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because you might have created/selected other connection in deploy wizard. Same is confirmed in the deployed connection string where you can see two connnection strings.

The second connection string is also referecened in EF seciton -

And, in the context you have used first connectionstring - public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {}

Changing name here will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks @jitendra. This make sense. But do you know how can I get rid of this 'other' connection? I never intended to create one, in fact it has been created for me during the deployment process I believe. I would like to use "DefaultConnection" for both development and production.

Comment: Try to uncheck the using this connection string option in Deploy Wizard, as you already have one. This might help.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I would love to hear the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have more control on the migration process you can handle the migration in the **Startup.Auth** by creating the context and use the **DBMigrator()** class to apply any pending migration:

```
//Get the connection string
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"];

//Instanciate the sql connection string builder
var builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString.ConnectionString);

//Create your context
var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(builder.ConnectionString);

//Check for null (Handle issue here).
if (dbContext == null) return;

//Get your configuration and specify the target database
var config = new Migrations.Configuration();
config.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(builder.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");

//Create the migrator using your config
var mig = new DbMigrator(config);

//Check for any pending migration to speed up the process and Update
//The migration will be applied here each time the application is published on azure   
if(mig.GetPendingMigrations().Any())mig.Update();
```

While this may not solve your issue directly, it allow more control and you should be able to see if the migration is not applied with a little debbuging.